# How to compare "mm:ss" 1 mile run times to detmine which is faster

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare mile run times with the times listed in the presidential physical fitness chart to determine if a runner's time is faster than the minimum listed in the chart, or not.

This comparison turns cell "A1" black

```
If TimeValue("11:00") > TimeValue("10:00" Then
Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 5
End If
```

When cell 2,14 contains 12:00 and cell 3,12 contains 11:40 
This comparison gives me: Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

```
If TimeValue(Worksheets("Individual_Stats").Cells(2, 14)) > TimeValue(Worksheets("PRT_Scores").Cells(3, 12)) Then
Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 5
End If
```

How can I compare two mm:ss times to see which is greater or lesser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the [TimeValue function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/timevalue-function), it expects you to pass it a String that can be interpreted as a time value. When you store a time value in a worksheet cell, it converts the value into a fraction of 24 hours and stores it as a floating point number.

So, the value "12:00" in a worksheet cell is stored as "0.5" because it is seen as 12 hours. When you then call `TimeValue` on the value of that cell, it's equivalent to `TimeValue(0.5)`. The argument passed isn't a String that can be interpreted as a time value and thus you get a type mismatch.

Also, to store the value of 12 minutes and zero seconds in a cell, you need to enter "00:12:00" - i.e. use hh:mm:ss format. If you only specify two values then this will be interpreted as hh:mm format which you can verify by inputting a value like "45:30".

To actually compare the values, you can try the following (using r1 and r2 to represent the two cells that you want to compare):

- `r1.Value < r2.Value`

This is the simplest comparison but it could give incorrect results if either of the cells is formatted as Text and stores the time value as a String rather than a floating point number

- `DateDiff("s", r1.Value, r2.Value) > 0`

The [DateDiff function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/datediff-function) tells you how many time units have elapsed between two date/time values - the "s" parameter indicates that we want to count seconds.

A positive result indicates that the second date/time was later than the first. A negative result indicates that the second date/time was earlier than the first. This function can successfully compare floating point values with string values - `DateDiff("s",8.33333333333333E-03,"00:11:40")` will return -20 as expected.

- `TimeValue(r1.Text) < TimeValue(r2.Text)`

This uses the displayed text of the worksheet cell rather than the stored value. If the displayed text changes then the comparison could be incorrect. If the cell format was changed from General to Number causing the text to change from "00:12:00" to "0.008333" then a type mismatch error could occur

---

All three solutions can work in some circumstances but I would lean towards using `DateDiff`. Comparisons like this are what that function is designed to do

Comment: Your suggestion to use DateDiff works perfectly.  Can I used something like `Worksheets("PRT_Scores").Columns(12).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss"` to make sure that the number format is always set correctly?

Comment: Yes - setting the number format that way should be fine